# I got this error when click on add new item in Menu Items Manager in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for Sm_Megamenu_Block_Adminhtml_Menuitems_Edit_Tab_Form::_getOrderByParentId(), called in /var/www/vhosts/websiteName.in/httpdocs/includes/src/Sm_Megamenu_Block_Adminhtml_Menuitems_Edit_Tab_Form.php on line 186 and defined  in /var/www/vhosts/websitName.in/httpdocs/includes/src/Sm_Megamenu_Block_Adminhtml_Menuitems_Edit_Tab_Form.php on line 532
```

Answer (score 0):

1) It clearly says argument 1 is missing.

2) Its just a warning. Though its a good practice to fix these warnings but you can stop this also. Probably your php error reporting is on which is this `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and Magento is in developer mode `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true)`.

You can find both in `index.php` in magento root folder.

Comment: I didn't changed anything form last 3 months to this project previously it was working perfectly. Now why argument is missing any idea.

Comment: Sorry i dont have any idea because this is custom theme. But probably the warning was still there.... only it was no visible. But now you have enabled the error reporting and thats why it shows up.